# How to convert bytes to a string of the same length in Python (1 character for each byte)?

Tags: python, django

I need a random string that I can write down to use for salt in a hash function. I can generate some random bytes and see them as hex:

```
import os, binascii
print(binascii.b2a_hex(os.urandom(32)))
b'76449cd6134d64353122102fcb512d1eae1bd8437202b6e06e91a422ce9e386b' # 64 chars
```

Great, but how do I convert these bytes directly to a string i.e. not necessarily printable, but exactly 32 characters? The hash function requires a string, not a "bytes" type with a maximum length of 32.

I'm not sure how to do the encoding in Python, but I guess I need something similar to the way an old 8-bit computer or a C program would turn a byte into a character (ASCII or other).

This is for the salt input of Django's make_password function.

Comment: ASCII defines only 7 bits. To represent the 8th bit you have to choose an encoding like for example iso-8859-1. It might be better to see the data just as binary data and not as characters.

Comment: You can't, because some of those bytes don't correspond to characters in ASCII.

Comment: What's that hash function that doesn't like `bytes`?

Comment: Unless an ASCII encoder exists in python (I'm not aware of one), your best bet would probably be to create a dictionary object that maps the 127 ASCII characters to their byte equivalents. That being said, if a character in the string doesn't exist in ASCII, you will have to come up with a way to deal with that. Maybe throw an exception, or encode it as 128 (the eighth bit flipped) though with that approach you would probably have to write a custom decoder as well.

Comment: Why use ASCII specifically as your salt, though? Why not use hexadecimal or base64 that have less esoteric support?

Comment: You're right about the ASCII characters. I edited my quesiton. But I still need a way to deirectly convert the "bytes" type into a string.

Comment: @superb rain it's Django's make_password function.

Comment: [bytes.decode](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) for decoding a bytes object into a string, but you could instead take a look at the [secrets module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html)

Comment: @Shiri too long by double!

Comment: did you try ".tobytes().decode()"?

Comment: @gornvix Checking the documentation for the `make_password` function, I see no specification that the salt must be 32 characters long. It does, however, specify that the salt must be _either_ a string or a bytes object. So this exercise is unnecessary - just give it the bytes.

Comment: @Abion47 Can you link to that, where it says the *salt* can be bytes?

Comment: @superbrain I'm looking [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/passwords/), but granted I may have misread the claim that the salt can be bytes. The point about the length constraint stands, though.

Comment: @Abion47 Yeah, I've seen that before, but it says that only about the password, not about the salt (as far as I saw). The salt parameter description is rather lacking. I tried looking at source code but that didn't help, either.

Comment: I said 32 as the function threw an exception when I tried to pass it a salt of length 40. However there seems to be some sort of unpredictability about the make_password function. As when I changed my program it went passed a length of 40 for the salt. I guess it is to deter hackers.

Comment: @Abion47 whatever the documentation says the function won't accept bytes for the salt parameter, only a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `chr` and join them:

```
>>> s = ''.join(map(chr, os.urandom(32)))
>>> print(len(s), s)
32 ^Ô¸ÒÜì<ù³B_¶t¶Ùj)"×Ï‚ž™Të$)
```

Or `decode` with let's say latin1:

```
>>> s = os.urandom(32).decode('latin1')
>>> print(len(s), s)
32 ùLÖ]ù²ì¥Ý.b#AÎ+Ûê+9'Za37
```

If you do need to go through such a hex string of length 64, just unhex it first:

```
>>> b = b'76449cd6134d64353122102fcb512d1eae1bd8437202b6e06e91a422ce9e386b'
>>> s = binascii.a2b_hex(b).decode('latin1')
>>> print(len(s), s)
32 vDÖMd51"/ËQ-®ØCr¶àn¤"Î8k
```

Or starting from random 32 bytes, hex them for show and decode them (without hex+unhex) for use:

```
>>> b = os.urandom(32)
>>> binascii.b2a_hex(b)
b'5751b7bfe1a3ea50c9f8143d64f4ce07a05a21805c976536147114dab27ee08c'
>>> s = b.decode('latin1')
>>> print(len(s), s)
32 WQ·¿á£êPÉø=dôÎ Z!\e6qÚ²~à
```

Comment: I can't write that down.

Comment: @gornvix Your computer can. Why would you? And you even allowed "not necessarily printable".

Comment: Right. I need to write it down (e.g. in hex) and then convert it to raw "not necessarily printable".

Comment: @gornvix How is that "directly" then?

Comment: rain as in the way the computer does it, for example Linux is written in C.

Comment: Under the bonnet, like for example in a terminal window the computer is storing the characters as bytes. That's the way C works. I need some bytes that I can write down, but I need to be able to convert them to string because that's what the function that I'm using takes. So I'm talking about two different strings that represent the same information.

Comment: Ok, that will solve my problem. But why "latin"? Why not the "native" or "built in" encoding on my computer, in my case Linux?

Comment: @gornvix Because latin1 is 8-bit single-byte, and probably the most common one. Unlike utf8, for example. If I try `os.urandom(32).decode()`, I get a `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte` because almost certainly the random bytes aren't valid utf8.